# SQL Тип данных для колонки

Tags: sql

Нужно сохранять десятичные числа с точностью (precision) 25 и масштабом (scale) 10. Какой тип данных следует выбрать для колонки?

Comment: А СУБД какая? mysql, posgresql, ms sql?

Comment: ну вообще-то sql. У меня есть два варианта, либо real(25, 10) либо numeric(25, 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логично предположить, что `decimal(35, 10)` - он чем-то не устраивает?